# R error in xy.coords

Tags: r, plot

I am using the R package "sdcMicro" and I have tried a working example at `?sdcMicro`, but cannot use the plot method.

Working example:

```
install.packages("sdcMicro", depend = TRUE)
library(sdcMicro)

data(free1)
f <- freqCalc(free1, keyVars = 1:3, w = 30)
ind <- indivRisk(f)
class(ind)
[1] "indivRisk"

plot(ind)
```

I get the message:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

If I try `methods(class = indivRisk)` I get:

```
[1] print.indivRisk
```

According to (http://www.tdp.cat/issues/tdp.a004a08.pdf), the methods of class "indivRisk" should be

```
plot.indivRisk print.indivRisk
```

The plot method helps analysis of data.

I don't understand why I don't have this method. Can anyone help me or guide me to an explaination?

I am using RGui (64-bit) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; there is no `print.indivRisk` method.

Looking at the structure of `ind`:

```
str(ind)
## List of 5
##  $ rk    : num [1:4000] 0.00121 0.00421 0.00421 0.00421 0.00169 ...
##  $ method: chr "approx"
##  $ qual  : num 1
##  $ fk    : int [1:4000] 8 3 3 3 6 6 4 7 5 3 ...
##  $ knames: chr [1:3] NA NA NA
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr "indivRisk"
```

maybe you just want a histogram of the `rk` element.

```
hist(ind$rk)
```

or

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(rk = ind$rk), aes(rk)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions. Unfortunately the plot(s) should be the base of analysis and derivation. Sisse

Comment: This tutorial is an outdated one. Some other functions like for local suppression also do not work the way it's mentioned in the tutorial. You can check https://sdcpractice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html for understanding the package.